# Filtering Product Collection on the basis of visibility

Tags: product, catalog, visibility

I want to remove the products from the product collection that are set Non-Individually Visible.

Here is my code:

```
  $validProductsCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
            $validProductsCollection->addFieldToFilter(ValidProductsInterface::DEMO_ID, $feedId)
                ->setPageSize($itemsPerPage)
                ->setCurPage($currentPage)
                ->addFieldToSelect(ValidProductsInterface::VALID_PRODUCT_ID);
            $collectionSize = $validProductsCollection->getSize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should the `addFieldToFilter` method with the `visibility` attribute to exclude products with a visibility value of "Not Visible Individually". We used the `neq` (not equal) operator to filter out those products.

```
$validProductsCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
$validProductsCollection->addFieldToFilter(ValidProductsInterface::DEMO_ID, $feedId)
    ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', ['neq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE])
    ->setPageSize($itemsPerPage)
    ->setCurPage($currentPage)
    ->addFieldToSelect(ValidProductsInterface::VALID_PRODUCT_ID);
$collectionSize = $validProductsCollection->getSize();
```

This modification should remove the products set as "Non-Individually Visible" from your product collection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

To remove products from the product collection that are set as "Non-Individually Visible," you can add an additional filter to exclude those products. Assuming **"Non-Individually Visible"** is a custom attribute

You can modify your existing code as follows:

```
$validProductsCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
$validProductsCollection->addFieldToFilter(ValidProductsInterface::DEMO_ID, $feedId)
    ->addFieldToFilter('non_individually_visible', ['neq' => 1]) // Exclude non-individually visible products
    ->setPageSize($itemsPerPage)
    ->setCurPage($currentPage)
    ->addFieldToSelect(ValidProductsInterface::VALID_PRODUCT_ID);
$collectionSize = $validProductsCollection->getSize();
```

**addFieldToFilter('non_individually_visible', ['neq' => 1])**

Adds a filter condition to exclude products where the "non_individually_visible" attribute is not equal to 1. Adjust the attribute name ('non_individually_visible') according to your actual attribute name.

By applying this filter, the resulting **$validProductsCollection** will only contain products that are individually visible.

Comment: I am getting the magento default product collection. So what I can use for the field to filter " non_individually_visible"

Comment: @RanaZain For default Magento the field name would be ```visibility```, check @HuanTH answer